# How to interpret coefficients relative to one another (regression) continuous and binary

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, predictive-models, regression-coefficients

I have a mix of continuous and binary data. promotion here is binary so 1= yes 0=no. i standardize (mean 0 and s.d. 1 ) the continuous variables so they are same unit.

I get the following output:

[image]

is this the correct interpretation?

- **a one unit s.d increase in temperature increase the s.d in products sold by 1030** therefore it has a large affect ; if we compare this to costs, costs has a greater coeff than temperature and therefore is more important
- **for binary** : if we run a promotion we can expect an increase in 5727 units sold.
- **since coeff is greater for promotion than any others it is much more important feature** : this one i struggle with, since the data for binary is not standardized and the coefficient has a different meaning is it right to compare relative importance between binary and continuous  --  if not how can i RANK the predictors against one another?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You shouldn't compare continuous and binary features without a transformation.</strike> In this situation (because promotion seems to be important) I would make the continuous variables into binary variables by assigning a 1 or 0 based on the range, for example:

Temperature between 0-32:  1 or 0
Temperature between 33-70: 1 or 0
Temperature between 70-90: 1 or 0
Temperature above 90:      1 or 0

Now you have *four* new binary features that represent temperature. You can now run a regression model and safely compare the coefficients with "promotion." Do the same for costs.

Caution: don't add too many binary features! For regression you should try and keep the number of coefficients under 10. If you add too many coefficients it will artificially inflate your R^2 value.

Comment: -1 There is no issue mixing continuous and binary variables in a regression. ANCOVA with two groups is one example. Further, binning data like this loses information. It says that 32 and 33 are less alike than 70 and 33.

Comment: Dave my mistake on mixing the variables, thanks for the correction. Binning can be helpful in this case, but you are right there is a trade-off. The ranges I picked are pretty arbitrary I leave it up to Maths12 to find the best ones.

Comment: How do you figure that the binning helps in this case?

Comment: If you bin and run regression you can learn if temp's effect changes over its range.

Comment: Robert Long and others on here have addressed that on here and how splines are superior if you’re concerned that temperature should have a nonlinear term.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thank you for pointing it out. Perhaps you can write an answer for Maths12 and help them out.